# Returning references to CUDA-specific vector types

Tags: c++, cuda

I would like to implement `f1` with the argument and return value exactly as in the code below.
It fails with the error:

```
a reference of type "float1 &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "float"
```

However, almost the same function `f2` with a native C++ type `float` instead of CUDA-specific wrapper `float1` works nicely.

https://godbolt.org/z/1j1e1r98d

```
__device__ float1& f1(float4& v) {
    return v.x; // ERROR
}

__device__ float& f2(float4& v) {
    return v.x; // OK
}
```

How I can change the implementation of `f1` to fix this error?

Comment: Isn't float1 a different struct from float4? You are trying to implicitly convert the `float x` from `float4&` to a `float1&`. They are different types. Your second version works, because `float4::x` is a float.

Comment: @BasGroothedde I assume that `float1` and `float` have the same memory representation, this is why I expect that `f1` should work. I am not converting float4 to float1, but float to float1.

Comment: I get that, however my point was that you are trying to implicitly convert a float type to a float1 struct instance reference. You could try this; https://godbolt.org/z/hYqofMr5M - but I consider that to be a very dirty solution. One cannot guarantee alignment like this.

If you don't need a reference, construct a float1 instance with v.x instead.

Comment: @BasGroothedde It seems to be a good solution since CUDA guarantees to align float4 to 16 bytes and float1 to 4 bytes (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#vector-types)

Comment: I think its still a much better solution to do `float1 out=v.x; return out`. The compiler should optimize if possible, if thats your worry.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I want to use result in assignments (e.g. for operator[] overloading) `f1(float4_instance) = float1_instance`

Comment: @AnderBiguri agreed, however OP wants a reference and using your solution you will be returning a reference to a temporary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution was discussed in the comments and there I also stated that I find this a bit dirty, however if CUDA specification guarantees the alignment of the `float4` and `float1` values then this could be a valid option;

```
__device__ float1& f1(float4& v) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<float1*>(&v);
}

__device__ float& f2(float4& v) {
    return v.x;
}
```

In this solution, you reinterpret the address of `v` as a pointer to `float1`. You can then dereference the result to have `v` as `float1&`.

Be careful with `reinterpret_cast` and different `struct`'s when it comes to alignment and offsets.

In the [Compiler Explorer Example](https://godbolt.org/z/W1daoranK) you can see both functions produce the exact same output.